# Hiding and showing several iframes in one page every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the most efficient way to show and hide iframes in a page every x time?

I was thinking on using a setInterval on a function that uses jQuery's hide and show but this seems inneficient and not very scalable if I needed to hide and show 1 out of 10 iframes in one page that I would also need to hide and show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            setInterval(function() {

                if ($('#basic').is(":visible") && $('#advanced').not(":visible") ) {

                    $('#basic').hide();
                    $('#advanced').show();
                }else if($('#basic').not(":visible") && $('#advanced').is(":visible")) {

                    $('#basic').show();
                    $('#advanced').hide();
                }else if($('#basic').is(":visible") && $('#advanced').is(":visible")) {

                    $('#basic').hide();
                    $('#advanced').show();
                };

            }, 30000);
         });
```

Each id refers to 1 iframe so right now I am only dealing with 2 iframes. The reason I have that last if else statement is because both iframes are being displayed when I load the page.

Comment: Then save in a variable the state of which frames are visible and which ones aren't. Then you only have to open 1 of the 10 and close all the open ones instead of toggling everything again. Cache the nodes as well if you aren't already.

Comment: It's always best to attempt it first, then come here for advice :)

Comment: @JonathanBrooks thank you for your feedback. Updated the post!

Comment: @Shilly how would you detect all those elements that are visible and all those that are hidden?

Comment: reason for down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Just a snippet since the OP asked for it. Posting as an answer so I can format the code a bit better. (warning: I haven't 100% tested it myself yet, this isn't meant as a copy/paste implementation.)

This should show all the hidden frames and hide all the visible frames every 30 sec.
You can obviously easily extend it to only show/hide specific nodes that you can reference by id since frames[theFramesID] will give you the reference and visible status. If you don't need to be able to access specific frames, you can obv simplify this and use an array instead of an object.

Just using some form of loop and caching your nodes instead of requerying the same node over and over again will already increase the scalability. Since you don't need to change the code once you add another frame.

One could probably replace the vanilla functions I used with jquery specific ones if needed. I'm not sure which version of jquery has built-in reduce.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var frames = $('iframe').reduce(function ( accumulator, frame ) {
            accumulator[frame.id] = {
                'reference' : frame,
                'visible' : frame.is(":visible")
            };
            return accumulator;
        }, {});
    setInterval(function() {
        Object.keys(frames).forEach(function ( id ) {
            var frame = frames[id];
            if (frame.visible) {
                frame.visible = false;
                frame.reference.hide();
            }
            else {
                frame.visible = true;
                frame.reference.show();
            }
        });
    }, 30000);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Shilly. I am having some trouble to implement this as I am not too familiar with vanilla